# What are the font settings used on native UITabBarItem

Tags: fonts, uitabbaritem

I'm trying to duplicate the naive font settings used on a UITabBarItem for use on a custom tabbar.

Does anyone know what the font settings are?  What UIFont, font size, text color, etc...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used the settings below to replicate the native font:

```
UILabel* tabBarItemLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
tabBarItemLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
tabBarItemLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:153.0/255.0 green:153.0/255.0 blue:153.0/255.0 alpha:1];
tabBarItemLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor clearColor];
tabBarItemLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

dessy's answer, in Swift (and for iOS 8):

```
    self.versionLabel = UILabel()   
    self.versionLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.versionLabel.text = "Some string"
    self.versionLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10.0)
    self.versionLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 153.0/255.0, green: 153.0/255.0, blue: 153.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```